# What is the idiomatic way to get a user's email from Xero's OAuth flow

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, xero-api

I have a web app which uses the `Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2Client` package to allow for authentication with Xero.

Once the user is redirected back into my app, I use the `IXeroClient.RequestAccessTokenAsync` method to exchange their code for an `IXeroToken` object, which allows me to make calls against the Xero API, as expected.

The one thing I do not know how to do, and which I can't seem to find in the official documentation, is how do I extract the user's details (namely their name and email address) from the `IXeroToken` object.

As per the standard, the information is encoded as JWT string in the `IdToken` property, but I am not sure how I am meant to get the information out of it without an additional dependency.

Answer (score 2):

The built in `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken` class can deserialize the `IdToken` payload.

`new JwtSecurityToken(accessToken.IdToken).Claims` contains all the claims in the token.

The relevant types are:

- `email` - The user's email
- `xero_userid` - The user's id (guid)
- `given_name` - The user's first name
- `family_name` - The user's last name

The claims' existence is obviously conditional to the appropriate scope being set.